# Which receiving address does my block reward go to when mining through bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-reward, server, coinbase-transaction

I'm wondering where goes the BTC as my bitcoin server finds a block?

Using bitcoind, I see no setting for a bitcoin address..

Comment: I guess it makes a new address for the reward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=16823.0), bitcoind creates a new address for the block reward and puts it directly in your `wallet.dat` file.

I suppose it is stored in your default wallet, but as a new address.